# Select records that are not stored in database in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

is there a way to select data that are not stored database using sql?
i want is to select those datas that are not stored in database.
if i have this code what should i do?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$contact = $_POST['contact']; 

$sql = mysql_query("select * from tbluser where name<>'$name' and contact<>'$contact'");
```

the value inside the name and contact in $_POST is not stored in database. how to do it?

UPDATE

i figured out the answer thank you for the Suggestions and Answers :)

here's my final query

```
$qq = mysql_query("select * from tbluser 
                   where not exists (select * from tbluser 
                                     where name='$name' 
                                       and contact='$contact')");
```

Comment: did you run this query in mysql server?

Comment: i try the query but nothing happen.

Comment: i have tested it locally it is working fine

Comment: @user3396263 of course nothing will happen, what do you expect to happen? You said those values are not in the database, so if your query runs correctly, it returns empty record-set and your code continues. Just check the value of `$sql` to see whether it has records or not and continue accordingly.

Comment: what to do you use after sql statement? a mysql_num_rows or mysql_fetch_array? or something like.

Comment: You can use any method you like, all will work. For instance, if you use `mysql_num_rows`, then when it is 0 then you know the values are not in the database.

Comment: thank you for your comments i just figured out the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

this query seems okay. you should use [`mysql_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_escape_string)

try like this:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$contact = mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact']); 

$sql = mysql_query("select * from tbluser where name<>'$name' and contact<>'$contact'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { //fetach the result
    echo $row["name"];
    echo $row["cantact"];
}
```

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated you should move to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: am i going to use mysql_num_rows() to count the records or what?

Comment: @user3396263: try my updated answer. you will have echoing name and contact if any thing found in the database

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from tbluser where name != '$name' and contact != '$contact'");
```

You should also use

```
mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

See http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: `!=` and `<>` are same

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to see if the values for NAME and CONTACT are on tbluser, and if they are not, you want to have the entered values returned with feedback indicating they are not on the table.

This should do that:

```
select 'not on table' as confirm, '$name' as name, '$contact' as contact
  from dual
 where not exists (select 'x'
          from tbluser
         where name = '$name'
           and contact = '$contact')
```

And if you want feedback indicating whether it is or isn't on the table (both ways), as some kind of check query, use:

```
select 'not on table' as confirm, '$name' as name, '$contact' as contact
  from dual
 where not exists (select 'x'
          from tbluser
         where name = '$name'
           and contact = '$contact')
union all
select 'is on table' as confirm, '$name' as name, '$contact' as contact
  from dual
 where exists (select 'x'
          from tbluser
         where name = '$name'
           and contact = '$contact')
```

Comment: Nice try, but that's too much unnecessary coding and performance loss for no valid reason. If the query returns no records then they're not there. You already have the values, so why you want the query to return what you already know? What does that achieve?

Comment: Try running "select 'x' from dual" against a database... pretty simple query. I would venture to guess it never takes more than a fraction of a second. And the subquery is the query that you would have to run anyway to get the empty result set. It is also the answer to his question "how to select data that doesn't exist in the database"

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter how little loss it causes, it is still an unnecessary loss. And look at your query, 13 lines to check if two values exist in a table? Yes, you answered the question to the letter, I'll give you that, but don't you think the question is not well-formed and we should be a little forgiving when we offer the help? It's not too hard to guess what OP really wanted or ask for a clarification.

Comment: There is likely no net measurable performance loss given that the alternative is to just do the same thing in php. Whether it would be easier or involve fewer lines of code using sql vs. php is also somewhat dependent on why he wants to do what he asked in his question. We really don't know the purpose of the page he's making, is it a simple check to see if 2 values are on the table, or does he want output if the 2 values are on the table, etc. and that influences what the 'best approach' might be.

Comment: thank you for the both of you. i just figured out the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

About Security , You should validate your input before save it in your database, this is about security issue ;)